# CSS positioning not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have one problem with internet explorer about css div positioning.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/jPaaGK)** from codepen.io .

If you check this demo with chrome or firefox then you can see the .test div positioning vorking correctly but when you open the demo with internet explorer then you can see the .test div shifted to the left side. How can i fixed this problem to work all browser anyone can help me in this regard ?

```css
    .test {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      height: auto;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      max-width: 580px;
      min-width: 300px;
      margin-top: 64px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      padding-top: 2px;
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06), 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
      -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0588235) 0px 1px 1px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 5px 0px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      -o-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      min-height: 840px;
    }
.header {
  height: 12rem;
  background: #009688;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: If you can add another wrapper to .test DIV and make that position:relative, this issue should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
position : absolute
```

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

So you need to specify position (`position:relative | fixed | absolute` i.e. any position apart form static) to the parent (this case body or html)

Comment: Yes you are right but i i want to add some div under the .test div. Like demo. Please check DEMO again please.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine without `position: absolute;`

https://jsfiddle.net/agnmx7s6/1/

Answer (score 0):

To center align the DIV below code enough.

```
    body{text-align:center}
```

Remove the below code in .text class

<s>position: absolute;</s>

Comment: This is working fine but if i use `body{text-align:center}` then all the text is centering. It is not good for me Mr.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without `absolute` positioning.

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/agnmx7s6/4/

Also added negative `margin-top` to the center div.